# How to open CLI in Lubuntu on Ubuntu host in Virtualbox when GUI is crashed?

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu

I'm running Lubuntu 18 guest on Ubuntu 18 host in Virtualbox 5.2.
But GUI is crashed and I see black screen when starting this virtual machine.

Trying to get into CLI in guest by CTRL+ALT+F1 shortcut. But instead of getting into CLI in guest, my host machine locked.
CTRL+ALT+F1 works when I run Lubuntu 18 guest on Windows host, bot not works on Ubuntu 18 host.

So how to get to CLI mode in Lubuntu 18 guest on Ubuntu 18 host?

Comment: Try 'host' + F1. The 'host' key is usually the right ctrl button, so press that and F1. Lemme know how that works for you. It should work with F2, F3, etc...

Comment: Right ctrl + F1 works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From my comments.

It needs to be done with the 'host' key. In the default configuration, that's <kbd>RIGHT CTRL</kbd>. Add that to the 'function' key, <kbd>F1</kbd> and that's how you enter <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

If you have changed your 'host' key, it will obviously be different. If you want to change it, or change it back, then this is where you do that:

[image: virtualbox preferences]

Answer (score 0):

If you have networking on the VM and it booted, you should still SSH and get a Command line.

But you also can go to the Menu of Virtual Box and indicate:
Input > Keyboard > Soft Keyboard.

[image]

You can send keystrokes like CTRL + ALT + F1.

Comment: SSH not enabled. And there is no Soft Keyboard in Virtualbox 5.2. Maybe it present only in Virtualbox 6?

Comment: Also normally CTRL + ALT + F2 or F3 or F4 and F5 also work. Can you boot with an emergency repair USB or a live USB. You can use Ubuntu live for example, and if it starts well, then mount the hard drive and troubleshot/fix.